# MPI_Gather junk in receiving buffer (MPI+C)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am new to MPI and trying to parallelize the code on multiple threads. I need to communicate a big chunk of data back to the master thread, and can't clean up the memory garbage I get after MPI_Gather. Here is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank, world_size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

double *total=NULL;
double parcial[15000];
int W=world_size*15000;

if (rank == 0) {
    total=malloc(sizeof(double) * world_size*15000);
}
else if (rank != 0) {
    for(int i=0; i<15000; i++)parcial[i] = rank*i*0.1;
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(rank==0) for(int ii=0; ii<W; ii++)total[ii]=0.;

MPI_Gather(parcial,15000,MPI_DOUBLE,total,15000,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (rank == 0) {
    int N=world_size*15000;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%f ", total[i]);
}

free(total);
MPI_Finalize();

}
```

If you run the code with multiple threads (I have tried 3,4,5...), it always has junk in the beginning of the receiving buffer even though I explicitly put total[ii] to zero before calling MPI_Gather and set a barrier. Is it because I physically have only two kernels? But I have read that MPI creates a virtual machine anyways. Is there a way to clean it and get a reliable gather?

**Addition:**

I figured, this junk is probably coming form zero-th thread. Why doesn't it go to zero after line 25?

Comment: Is it the same garbage that is in `parcial` on the root process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from the MPI man page for MPI_Gather:

> Each  process  (root  process  included) sends the contents of its
>   send buffer to the root process.

Thus, the first 15000 elements of the recv buffer `total` will contain the elements of `parcial` on the root process. This was left unitialized in your code.

Edit: @Gilles commented that `MPI_IN_PLACE` could be used to avoid initialization on the root process.  Here's an example showing its effect:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int *in_place_total = calloc(sizeof(int), size);
    int *total = calloc(sizeof(int), size);

    int sendval = rank-5000;

    MPI_Gather(&sendval, 1, MPI_INT,
           total, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0)
        assert(total[0] == -5000);

    if (rank)
        MPI_Gather(&sendval, 1, MPI_INT,
           in_place_total, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else
        MPI_Gather(MPI_IN_PLACE, 1, MPI_INT,
           in_place_total, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0)
        assert(in_place_total[0] == 0);

    free(total);
    free(in_place_total);

    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Comment: If you do not want to initialize `parcial` on rank 0, you might want to use `MPI_IN_PLACE`

Comment: Excellent point @GillesGouaillardet!  I've added an example to my answer